# JSON body exceeded maximum document size

Tags: spring-boot, angular2-services

When i am trying to upload a document of size even less then 5MB of **.txt** format
browser is showing **JSON body exceeded maximum document size** error. But the same  web service in postman is giving the correct response. Does angular have any post body length limitations? or Browser? or Server?.

Answer (score 0):

Check the content type, it must be set as application/json.